# Vertical align weird Chrome behaviour

Tags: html, css, firefox, google-chrome, cross-browser

I just noticed a weird behaviour with **Chrome**.
Applying a vertical-align property to the div the text node inside it is also aligned.

With **Firefox** the text node is ignoring the property as it should do.

Is it a Chrome bug ?
[Live example](http://jsfiddle.net/XqJ6j/2/)

```
<div>
  <input>
   text
</div>

div{
    vertical-align:top;
    font-size: 11px;
}
```

Comment: If you change it to text-top, it then matches in Chrome.

Comment: I dont know what you mean, but from what i see, you're aligning div. which means, div and everything inside will be vertical-align top. Your word "text", exists outside the input tag, which puts it in the div tag, and has no relation to the input tag. Hence, it would be aligned top. I might be wrong.

Comment: and btw, u have an extra '>' tag in your question.

Comment: Vertical align: `The vertical-align property affects the vertical positioning inside a line box of the boxes generated by an inline-level element.` http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/vertical-align

Comment: I thought the vertical-align property would affect only the element using the property and not its children. 
So in that case the Firefox implementation is wrong. Try my example on Firefox and you will see that the text is not verticaly aligned.

Comment: This looks like a webkit bug since all other browsers seem to behave as expected. Vertical-align doesn't apply to box level elements so it seems like webkit is either interpreting it wrong or trying to be helpful.

Comment: Like I commented before vertical-align work on inline element: http://www.cs.sfu.ca/CourseCentral/165/sbrown1/wdgxhtml10/inline.html Your `<div>` is not an inline element.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like the expected behavior of applying vertical-align: top to the div. If you want a simple fix, just apply a line-height to the div that is the height of the input box. That will vertically center the text to the right of the input.

```
div {
  vertical-align: top;
  font-size: 11px;
  line-height: 16px;
}
```